# Importing perforce projects into eclipse from plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, perforce, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to import a bunch of perforce projects into eclipse that are already checked out. They all have the necessary .project and .classpath files. For this I use a psf import file. I can do the File>Import>Team Project Set manually, and after setting the location of the file, the perforce plugin kicks in, and does all the hard work.

Now, I wish to do this automatically, from a plugin of my own. Currently this plugin of mine only creates a temporary psf file on the fly.

Ideally I would like to somehow pass the psf file's location to the perforce plugin, skipping the "Import a Team Project Set" dialog box altogether, and making it import the projects.

Alternatively, if that proves to be not possible, I would like to be able to open the "Import a Team Project Set" window from my plugin, automatically set the location of the temporary psf file on it, then hopefully "click" on the Finish button, so that the perforce plugin could again kick in, and do the work for me.

I've been looking for a solution for the past two days. Is there anyone who can help me with this? Thanks in advance.